# you need to load the kernel first

Tags: kernel, boot, system-installation, live-usb

After making live iso from `mkusb`, the iso file was `debian-live-10.4.0-amd64-xfce+nonfree.iso`, I have tried to boot from it. From bootloader menu (live persistent, live only, live to RAM, ... [other options]) I have selected first (that is live with persistent), then this error:

```
error: (hd0, gpt4)/live/vmlinuz-4.19.0-9-amd64 has invalid signature
error: you need to load the kernel first
```

Does anyone know, how to fix it (e.g. load it?)

Comment: Is 'secure boot' set in the UEFI/BIOS menu of your computer? In that case, please turn it off. The problem might be that the kernel lacks a signature to satisfy 'secure boot'.

Comment: mkusb is tested with the official (free) versions of Debian. I know that it works with `debian-live-10.4.0-amd64-standard.iso` and `debian-live-10.4.0-amd64-cinnamon.iso`. It might work with your iso file too - I am not sure, but it is worthwhile testing it  before resorting to a free version of Debian.

Comment: The next alternative is to try persistence according to **mkusb-plug**. You tested (standard) mkusb-dus, but it is possible that mkusb-plug will work better in your case. (But if the problem is 'secure boot' no mkusb version can fix it - 'secure boot' must be turned off for the computer to boot the kernel.)